# How to change bar size plotly time series

Tags: python, graph, histogram, plotly

I'm working on creating some analysis on a player's games over time for League of Legends. I'm trying to create a histogram using plotly, with the date range on the x axis and no. of games on y. This works but i can't get individual bars for each day, just month. I've tried using the xaxis, 'size' object but this doesnt change anything, I guess because the x axis is in date form.

So question, in Plotly how do I change the size of the bars on the histogram from a monthly bin size to daily bin size?

Here's an example of the code:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import random
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from plotly import tools
from plotly.offline import *#plotly.offline.iplot()
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
############## create date ranges #################

d1 = date(2014, 3, 22)  # start date
d2 = date(2014, 6, 22)  # end date

delta = d2 - d1         # timedelta
dates = []
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    dates.append((d1 + timedelta(days=i)))


#################################################


def games_p_day():
    sizeo = 1
    trace_total = go.Histogram(
        y=[random.randint(1, 10) for y in range(1, 100)],
        x=dates,
        name = 'total games',
        xbins=dict(
        size=sizeo
    )
        )
    trace_wins = go.Histogram(
        y=[random.randint(1, 10) for y in range(1, 100)],
        x=dates,
        name = 'won games',
        xbins=dict(
            size=sizeo
    )
        )
    trace_losses = go.Histogram(
        y=[random.randint(1, 10) for y in range(1, 100)],
        x=dates,
        name = 'lost games',
        xbins=dict(
        size=sizeo
    )
        )
    layout = dict(
        title = "Wins and losses over time",
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list([
                    dict(count=1,
                         label='1m',
                         step='month',
                         stepmode='backward'),
                    dict(count=6,
                         label='6m',
                         step='month',
                         stepmode='backward'),
                    dict(step='all')
                ])
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(),
            type='date',

        ),
        bargap=0.2,
        bargroupgap=0.1)
    data=[trace_total]
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    iplot(fig, filename = "Wins and losses over time")    

games_p_day()
```

Any help massively appreciated.
Oh and if you see anything else that could help me (ie. bad code structure) please let me know!

Comment: Does each line in data represent a day (i.e. each trace?)

Comment: No, each trace is intended to represent either wins losses or total over the date range. I want a bar for each day in that range. To make it simpler I'm actually just going to get rid of two of the traces since that doesn't apply to this problem. Plus I'll add a bar gap to separate the bars to show each bar more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A histogram is the [representation of the distribution](https://plot.ly/python/histograms/) of numerical data. It seems to me that what you're aiming to de here is an aggregation of data from daily to weekly data. That is, as long as you'd like to have a time dimension and not count, average or any other aggregation function on your x-axis. If this is the case then the key to your challenge lies not in plotly itself but in aggregation and time functions such as `resample('W-Mon', on='index').sum()`. Here are some examples:

**Plot for sampled raw data:**

[image]

**Code for raw data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# data
np.random.seed(12)
numdays=100
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=numdays)
games = np.random.randint(low=100, high=200, size=numdays).tolist()
losses = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=numdays).tolist()
wins = list(np.array(games)-np.array(wins))
df = pd.DataFrame({'games': games,
                        'wins':wins,
                        'losses':losses}, index=dates)

# resample daily data to weekly sums
df2=df.reset_index().resample('W-Mon', on='index').sum()
df2['formatted_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3.index)
df2['year'] = df2.formatted_date.apply(lambda x: x.year)
df2['week_of_year'] = df2.formatted_date.apply(lambda x: x.weekofyear)
df2['year_week'] = df2['year'].map(str)+'_'+df3['week_of_year'].map(str)

# build and show plotly plot for daily games
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(name='games', x=df.index, y=df['games'])])
fig.show()
```

**Plot for weekly aggregated data. Date as index:**

[image]

**Code for weekly aggregated data. Date as index:**

```
# build and show plotly plot for weekly games. Dates as index
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(name='games', x=df2.index, y=df2['games'])])
fig.show()
```

**Plot for weekly aggregated data. Year and week number as index:**

[image]

**Code for weekly aggregated data. Year and week number as index:**

```
# build and show plotly plot for weekly games. Year and week number as index
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(name='games', x=df2['year_week'], y=df2['games'])])
fig.show()
```

**Plot for weekly aggregated data, split on wins and losses:**

[image]

**Code for weekly aggregated data, split on wins and losses:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# data
np.random.seed(12)
numdays=100
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=numdays)
games = np.random.randint(low=100, high=200, size=numdays).tolist()
losses = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=numdays).tolist()
wins = list(np.array(games)-np.array(wins))
df = pd.DataFrame({'games': games,
                        'wins':wins,
                        'losses':losses}, index=dates)

# resample daily data to weekly sums
df2=df.reset_index().resample('W-Mon', on='index').sum()
df2['formatted_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3.index)
df2['year'] = df2.formatted_date.apply(lambda x: x.year)
df2['week_of_year'] = df2.formatted_date.apply(lambda x: x.weekofyear)
df2['year_week'] = df2['year'].map(str)+'_'+df3['week_of_year'].map(str)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(name='victory', x=df2['year_week'], y=df2['wins']),
                      go.Bar(name='defeat', x=df2['year_week'], y=df2['losses'])])



fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Comment: The answer you gave would have solved my problem. I totally forgot about this but I hope that your answer will help people in the future... Although I'm thinking the question is from my ignorance as a beginner... Maybe it's not helpful and should just be deleted to remove clutter on Stackoverflow?